# Excel Data Model not detecting relationships

Tags: excel, powerquery, data-modeling, powerpivot

I am struggling to get this simple data model to work in Excel's Data Model. I have 3 tables. One table is a large budget. The second table is a small budget. The last table is transactions. Each transaction is allocated to both a small budget and a large budget. I think my issue is because we can't use bi direction filtering with Excel's Data Model. When I try to use a field from the transaction table, there is no relationship to any of the budget table. Is there another way to set this up?

Please see pictures attached. Thanks!!!

[image: Tables]

[image: Relationships]

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that bi-directional filtering is not an option in Power Pivot, and so filtering only ever propagates from the one side to the many side. Which, in your case, means that the *Transaction* table cannot filter either of the other two tables.

Have you tried adding **Calculated Columns** to the *Transactions* table to pull in the Big Budget and Small Budget Values? For example, for Big Budget Value:

```
=
LOOKUPVALUE(
    BigBudget[Big Budget Value],
    BigBudget[Big Budget], 'Transaction'[Big Budget]
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that solution, but then the Big Budget Value is larger than it should be. The   total of Big Budget Value is 220, but it should be 90.

Answer (score 0):

I got it I think. You can use the CROSSFILTER measure.

=CALCULATE([Sum of Big Budget Value],CROSSFILTER(BigBudget[Big Budget],'Transaction'[Big Budget],Both))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).